# Cannot refresh feed in Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-feed

For quite a number of days now I've been unable to refresh the feed in the Android app. The error is below.

> Sorry, something went wrong trying to load the feed. Pull to refresh to try again.

[image: cannot refresh]

Update: now the feed is completely blank.

[image: entirely blank feed]

Comment: Your phone is gigantic!  How do you even lift it to your ear?  You must be really strong.

Comment: @Won't it's the standard massive resolution for new phones. Also way higher resolution than my laptop.

Comment: Nah, you've got a gigantic phone.  It's a thing all the hipsters are doing right now.  Plays havoc with their skinny jeans when they try to cram their comically large phones in their back pockets.

Comment: Are you able to access [direct link to HNQ source for mobile app](http://stackexchange.com/hot-questions-for-mobile)? Based from the error message, it seems that there's an error on refreshing the *feed* instead of HNQ, but the failure prevent the HNQ to be updated.

Comment: @Portal well that link does bring me somewhere.

Comment: @Matt better post that edit as a new answer instead and self-accepting it, for sake of others having same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installed Android system update, now the feed is functioning properly again.